# Spring wiring conditional to an environment

Tags: java, spring, autowired

With Spring wiring, if I have multiple implementations of an interface, I can use @Qualifier to specify which one I want.

E.g., assuming that I have a

```
@Component
@Qualifier("Toyota")
public class Toyota implements Car
```

and a

```
@Component
@Qualifier("Bmv")
public class Bmv implements Car
```

Then I can select a specific implementation with:

```
  @Qualifier("Toyota") Car car
```

But is there a way to select the implementation based on an environment?

I.e. if I have spring.profiles.active set to local, then I will select the 'Toyota' implementation of Car, but if spring.profiles.active is set to dev or stage, then I will select the 'Bmv' implementation of Car?

An example of the exact syntax would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, the solution is actually quite simple:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("Bmv")
@Profile("!dev")
public class Bmv implements Car
```

and

```
@Component
@Qualifier("Toyota")
@Profile("dev")
public class Toyota implements Car
```

This way, the wiring of Car will use Toyota for dev environment, and Bmv otherwise.

Comment: Yes, that will do what you want with the env being set. For the record, you can also set it up with configuration so that you don't have to use Qualifiers for your code, but it is just trading one approach for another. You can use the configuration to load an env based off of a system variable or, well, there are actually a few ways. Glad you figured out what you needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can injection both implementation and choose which one you need by parameter {spring.profiles.active},  such like this code :

```
@autowired
private Car Toyota;
@autowired
private Car Bmv;

public Car getCar(){
  if(spring.profiles.active is local){
        return Toyota;
  }else{
        return  bmv;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your example is simple and clear and does what I need if I had a single class where to use a Car instance but that method would become cumbersome if I had a large number of 20 classes all using the Car interface.  I could have a CarSelector with the getCar method you defined that all classes could leverage, but I was hoping that Spring offers something a bit more integrated.

Comment: @Lolo, I think you can using different spring xml config file for different runtime environment.

Answer (score 1):

Spring 3.1 introduced environment profiles: http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/

I personally do not like Qualifiers and using them the way you proposed in the code actually couples to the implementation rather than decouple. You can use the @Autowired element like Jason proposed, but couple that with the bean profiles like so:

`<beans profile="dev">
   <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/bank/config/sql/schema.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/bank/config/sql/test-data.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>
</beans>`

and then when you create the environment you specify a profile:

`<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>production</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>`

Comment: Point taken about qualifiers coupling the implementation.  I have trouble seeing though whether what you suggest could address the objection I just made to Jason's suggestion.  I.e. is there a way to tell Spring: "Whenever you see @Autowired Car car; used in _any_ class and the 'dev' profile is active, use the Toyota implementation.  Otherwise, use the Bmv implementation."

Comment: Just to make sure I understand it correctly, are you wanting Toyota if the Dev profile is active otherwise use the Bmv implementation? So if dev Car = Toyota, if prod Car = Bmv?

Comment: Exactly.  See the answer I proposed. This does exactly what I want.