# Setting different attribute name for an entity according to environment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ldap, spring-ldap

I'm writing an app which interacts with a Ldap user repository. I have two environments and the problem is that there's an attribute which has a different name in each of them. Is there a way to configure this so I don't have to build a version for each environment?

Answer (score 1):

You can code an abstraction on you repository class and inject based on envioriment
[Spring wiring conditional to an environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600425/spring-wiring-conditional-to-an-environment)

Comment: I tried with, but I couldn't make it work. I end up with one interface **UserRepository<T>**, which has a custom method **replaceAttribute**. Then other two interfaces which extends the previous one: **UserRepositoryLocal extends UserRepository<UserLocal>** and **UserRepositoryProd extends UserRepository<UserProd>**. And then, two implementations: **UserRepositoryLocalImpl** and **UserRepositoryProdImpl**. Both users classes implement User interface. My error is "No property replaceAttribute found for type User"

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 different configuration beans based on profile using @Profile annotation and in each use the attribute name for that env.

for example: suppose i have 2 env local and prod and a database connection property has different name in each env.

local : "local.db.con"
prod : "prod.db.con"

```
@Configuration
@Profile("local")
public LocalDBConfig{

@Value("${local.db.con}")
private String dbCon;

@Bean
public DataSource datasource{
  // use dbCon here
}

}
```

Similarly

```
@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
public ProdDBConfig{

@Value("${prod.db.con}")
private String dbCon;

@Bean
public DataSource datasource{
  // use dbCon here
}

}
```

Depending upon your profile either of the configuration will be loaded and DataSource bean will be created with the property

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. The thing is that I'm not sure how this can help because the problem I have is with one entry, which has an attribute like this: **@Attribute(name = "title") private String title;** but it should be **@Attribute(name = "another-title") private String title;** in the another environment. How do you configure that using the configuration above?

Comment: can you share some code. where are you using @Attribute?

Comment: Thank you for your time. This is my class `class User{ @Attribute(name = "title") private String title;}`. And I'm using it in a repository `public interface UserRepository extends LdapRepository<User>`.